# How to sort `divs` based on user's number of clicks using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a script that counts how many times the user clicks each link and sort their order based on that number...

It works fine as is, however it doesn't work if the `<a>` tags is nested inside a div. It's ignoring the `divs` and the content/image/icon inside, while showing only the links..

How to change it so that it will show and reorder the entire div instead of just the link?

Please see what I have so far:

```js
function updateClicks(ele) {
  const storage = window.localStorage.getItem(ele.innerHTML + " clicks");
  if (storage === null) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(ele.innerHTML + " clicks", "1");
  } else {
    var clicks = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem(ele.innerHTML + " clicks")) + 1;
    localStorage.removeItem(ele.innerHTML + " clicks");
    window.localStorage.setItem(ele.innerHTML + " clicks", clicks);
  }
}

function orderItems() {
  var order = [];
  var href = [];
  var links = document.getElementById("links-list");
  var link = links.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    href.push(link[i].href);
  }
  links = links.innerHTML.split("</a>");
  document.getElementById("links-list").innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < links.length - 1; i++) {
    var lastChar = links[i].charAt(links[i].length - 1);
    var clicks = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem(lastChar + " clicks"));
    if (isNaN(clicks)) {
      clicks = 0;
    }

    order.push([lastChar, clicks, href[i]]);
  }
  order.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1]
  });
  order.reverse();
  console.log(order)
  for (i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("links-list").innerHTML += "<a href='" + order[i][2] + "'  onclick='updateClicks(this)'>" + order[i][0] + "</a>";
  }
}
```

```css
.link-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.link-container a {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.link-img {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="orderItems();">

<div id="links-list">
  <div class="card link-container">
    <img class="link-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/6ZpMxiG.png" />
    <a href="#" onclick="updateClicks(this)">A</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card link-container">
    <img class="link-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/sFUFOyO.png" />
    <a href="#" onclick="updateClicks(this)">B</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card link-container">
    <img class="link-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/M5a2gh8.png" />
    <a href="#" onclick="updateClicks(this)">C</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card link-container">
    <img class="link-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/mbrEuvR.png" />
    <a href="#" onclick="updateClicks(this)">D</a>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

I'm still trying to learn JS and I need this feature for a project I'm building.. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: U could have updated it in your old question :D

Comment: How is this supposed to work if you are referring to the a tags only and not the div?

Comment: Move onclick="updateClicks(this)" event handler to DIV instead of A

Comment: Hi I'm sorry I didn't want to ask for more in that same thread.. Can you please show me how to tweak your code to handle `divs`?

Comment: `function updateClicks(ele) { ele = ele.parentNode;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of keeping track of the click counts and sorting the divs accordingly:

```js
// The cnt values in the divs array could be initialised from local storage:
const
  list=document.getElementById("links-list"),
  divs=[...list.querySelectorAll(".card")];
divs.forEach(e=>e.cnt=0)

list.onclick=ev=>{
  if (ev.target.tagName!=="A") return;
  ev.target.closest(".card").cnt++;
  divs.sort((a,b)=>a.cnt-b.cnt)
   .forEach(el=>list.append(el))
  console.log(divs.map(e=>e.textContent.trim()+e.cnt).join(","))
}
```

```css
.link-container {
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid grey;
}

.link-img {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body">

<div id="links-list">
  <div class="card link-container">
    <img class="link-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/6ZpMxiG.png" />
    <a href="#">A</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card link-container">
    <img class="link-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/sFUFOyO.png" />
    <a href="#">B</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card link-container">
    <img class="link-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/M5a2gh8.png" />
    <a href="#">C</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card link-container">
    <img class="link-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/mbrEuvR.png" />
    <a href="#">D</a>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```